# Nsinteger accessible issue

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsinteger

When I try to add nsinteger value into array it shows warning,

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') to parameter of type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int'); dereference with *

and crashed when reach the code

```
[sizary1 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:Quant.quantity]];
```

quantity declared as

```
 @property (nonatomic) NSInteger * quantity;
```

What change should I made?

Comment: Don't use pointer, use this  `@property (nonatomic) NSInteger quantity;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You are using `quantity` as a Pointer in this case.So `NSInteger` doesn't allow to pointer in this case.

2)You're passing `quantity` to numberWithInteger:, which takes an NSInteger. It's nothing to do with the setObject:. You probably want to either copy `quantity` or just pass in quantity to setObject: directly.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to have pointers to NSInteger values. It's not appropriate in this case but it is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

**No need for * in NSInteger** .Use

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger  quantity;
```

Crash

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:Quant.quantity]];
```

`numberWithInteger:` expect a value not its pointer reference so it crashes.

Make the property without `*` and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a pointer to the `NSInteger`. `NSNumber` requires the `NSInteger` itself, not a pointer to it. I would change your property to

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

NSInteger is a primitive type, which means it can be stored locally on the stack.  **You don't need to use a pointer to access it.** NSInteger is a primitive value type; you don't really need to use pointers. So your declaration should be

```
    @property (nonatomic) NSInteger quantity;
```